# LARAVEL 5.3, Get User Name and Role Name (Using Laravel Model Relationships)

Tags: php, laravel, model, relationship

Testgrammatical or spelling errors
► clarify meaning without changing it
► correct minor mistakes
► add related resources or links
► always respect the original author

Comment: Looks like you need to define a many-to-many relationship. `function roles(){return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'user_role');}`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel isn't this enough at the user model 
`public function roles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(UserRole::class);
    }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the data using [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading):

```
$user = User::where('id', $userId)->with('roles')->first();
```

Then display the data:

```
{{-- Display full name --}}
{{ $user->first_name.' '.$user->last_name }}

{{-- Display all role names of the user --}}
@foreach ($user->roles as $role)
    {{ $role->name }}
@endforeach
```

I guess relation here is many to many, so you need to change `roles()` relation to `belongsToMany()`

If you're using some package with many to many relationship, but you're only attach one role for user, you can display role name with this:

```
{{ $user->roles->first()->name }}
```

Also, you could use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) to get full name:

```
public function getFullNameAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->first_name.' '.$this->last_name;
}
```

To display full name using accessor:

```
{{ $user->full_name }}
```

Comment: hey, thanks man! i need all the users (so no user id) but i mnaged to get that.
but,

` {{$userrole->role->name}} //--worked fine
                                    @foreach ($userrole->role as $role)
                                        {{ $role->name }} // throws error
                                    @endforeach  `


ANY Idea??

Comment: @Vinuvasudev why are you using `$userrole` instead of `$user`?

Comment: actually am at user-role linking (so userrole)..
A single page to list all the users and their roles! and roles can be multi(one to many)

Comment: @Vinuvasudev you need to get all users with their roles, so you need to use `User` model here. `User::with('roles')->get();` Then iterate over `$users`. Also, since you have pivot table with `user_id` and `role_id` it's [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) and you should use `belongsToMany()`

Comment: I have a user-role table ( u can see my UserRole model up there ) so need to list all the users,roles! currently everything works other than many! But when i put belongToMany, got an error with an sql query showing about non existing table name and all

Answer (score 2):

```
@foreach($users as $user)
{{$user->name}}  {{$user->roles->first()->name}}

@endforeach
```